# Display 2 prices?

Tags: 7, ubercart

How can I display 2 prices for products? I'd like to display a price in the local currency and a price in USD for each product. Is it possible to do this through [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) configuration, or does it require custom code?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use this module for multi currency
https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_multi_currency

Comment: I was hoping for something that calculated prices based on a rate, rather than have to enter both currencies.